# Get multiple values using join in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server database. I have two tables in my database, `Type` and `Users`.

**Type** table:

```
Type    CreatedBy   ModifiedBy
------------------------------
Type1   1           2
Type2   3           4
Type3   2           3
```

**Users** table:

```
UserId  FirstName   LastName
----------------------------
1       John        Martin
2       Rose        Marry
3       Stefi       Pit
4       Nil         Sen
```

I want to run a query which returns this result:

```
Type    CraetedBy   ModifiedBy
-------------------------------
Type1   John Martin Rose Marry
Type2   Stefi Pit   Nil Sen
Type3   Rose Marry  Stefi Pit
```

I am new to SQL and not getting how to get values like this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This question is too easy to being asked, but...  May be you need to check a online course like this. I recommend you to take a look to: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

but is something like this:

```
select T.Type, U1.FirstName + U1.LastName as CreatedBy,  U2.FirstName + U2.LastName as ModifiedBy from Type T 
join Users U1 on U1.UserId = T.CreatedBy
join Users U2 on U2.UserId = T.ModifiedBy
```